# MultiThreading with Possible Long Delay

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have been studying up on writing apps with multiple threads accessing shared variables as I am about to write my first application that uses multiple threads!  I think I understand the risks of using multiple threads, but am unsure what the best approach is for my scenario.  In my app, I only have one Object which will be accessed by multiple threads.  I would like it to look something like this:

```
public class SharedObj {
    // Variables shared by all threads
    private String value1;
    private byte[] value2;
    // A connector which maintains a tcp connection and handles transactions with a server
    // It is used to update 'value1' and 'value2' with there values on the server
    private Connector connector;

    public void update() {
        String newValue1 = connector.getValue1();
        synchronized(this) {
            value1 = newValue1;
        }
        byte[] newValue2 = connector.getValue2();
        synchronized(this) {
            value2 = newValue2;
        }
    }

    public void setValue1(String newValue) {
        if(connector.updateValue1(newValue)) {
            synchronized(this) {
                value1 = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
    public String getValue1() {
        String ret;
        synchronized(this) {
            ret = value1;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I think a simple solution to this problem would be to make each function synchronized, but then when `update()` is called, the object could be locked for long periods of time, as the byte array can be virtually any size, and therefore take a long time to transmit over the network.  This is why I would only like to lock the object when variables are being read or changed, so that they can remain accessible without long delays.  I don't care if `setValue1()` or `update()` gets blocked for a long period of time, but the `getValue1()` function cannot be blocked for long periods of time.

Now back to the example above.  Let's assume that all functions in my Connector class are synchronized.  If that was the case, would the above example be considered safe?  My confusion is around exactly how synchronization works.  My concern would be that `update()` could be called by one thread, and be in the middle of the line `String newValue1 = connector.getValue1()` when another thread calls the function `setValue1("something")` and the connector object is used to call another function.  Since all functions in the Connector class are synchronized, would that be considered safe, or could both threads attempting to call a function on the same object still cause problems to occur?

Is there some other approach I should be using that would make this easier on me?  Pointing me towards any tutorials or documentation that could help me out would be great also!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `synchronized(x) { x = otherX; }` <-- this is not thread safe! You should use an `AtomicReference`; it is thread safe by definition, and you won't need to `synchronize` on it.

Comment: @fge Is it not thread safe because of memory consistency issues, or something else?  I could see how it could cause memory consistency issues, but if it causes other issues, could you please give more details as to why it's not thread safe?  Also, AtomicReference does look helpful, thanks, I will look into it further!

Comment: @user1725940 `synchronized(x)` acquires a lock on the object `x`, if you assign a new object to your `x` you change the object that is locked and that's not what you want (2 threads can be in the synchronized block if they happen to see two different x objects) Always synchronize on a never changing reference to a non-null object, e.g. `this` or `final Object lock = new Object()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) in Java tutorials you will see that the assignment of String and byte array can be considered atomic because are reference variables.

> - **Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables** and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
> - Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

Then the sentence `String newValue1 = connector.getValue1()` isn't problematic, because once the String is returned by the connector it will be consistent, moreover Strings are inmutable and the `Connector` will never can change the value.

Much more problematic is `connector.getValue2()` because the array could be modified by the connector in subsequent calls. This is dangerous even in a one-threaded application. Then you must be sure that the Connector won't modify the array once returned (maybe returning a copy in the getter)

What needs to be thread-safe is the `Connector` itself, if it isn't you cannot share  them between threads safely, in this case through `SharedObj`.